COPY INTO Optimization - Listing External Files
I am trying to optimize my COPY INTO command.
Loading data from ADLS Gen2 into Snowflake via External Stage.
ADLS Folder Pattern,
YYYY-MM-DDTHH24.MI.SSZ/METADATA/<TABLE>/<TABLE>.json
YYYY-MM-DDTHH24.MI.SSZ/<TABLE>/<TABLE>.csv

I have two seperate COPY to load the data into two seperate table given the file format is different.
Things tried,

Passing  in the stage path to reduce the scan to specific day.

COPY INTO TABLE
FROM ( SQL )
@EXT_STAGE/2024-08-01
PATTERN = 'T[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}Z/.*\.json$'

Still takes alot of time. Folders present for almost every 10 mins in ADLS.

Tried different patterns,

PATTERN = 'T[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}Z/.*\.json$' -- Found most effective
PATTERN = '.*T[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}Z/.*\.json$' -- Second Best
PATTERN = '.*\.json$' -- Third Best

Though the difference in time is very low.

Stats,

For 100k files processed, it is taking about 12 mins
Listing External Stage - 5 mins
Processing - 7 mins

Number of rows inserted
94479
Scan progress
100.00%
External bytes scanned
2.35GB
Bytes written
17.10MB

Considering the stats its just ~2 GB data and only 17 MB's written but execution time is quite high.
Let me know if there is any way to improve the execution time either by improving the PATTERN or any other way.
*Things which are not as per Snowflake recommendation,

Files are not compressed ( Can't compress it )


Since you ask for an upgrade for a working code, consider posting it at [codereview.se].

In your stats you say you processed 100k files but only loaded 94k records, so either most of your files are empty or they contain very few records. That’s probably a significant contributor to your performance issue: your file size is very inefficient for Snowflake to process
